# Unity - Change cube color before placement

Tags: unity-game-engine

So, I am making a Minecraft-like game, and you basically move around on a pre-generated floor and place blocks. My problem is that I need to get the ability for the player to change the block color by hitting a numberpad key, ex: 1 for red, 2 for blue, and so on.

Here is the script that generates the floor, and handles block placement.

```
var range : float = Mathf.Infinity;
var hit : RaycastHit;

for (var y = -4; y < 50; ++y)
for (var x = -4; x < 50; ++x) {
    var block : GameObject = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
    block.transform.position = transform.position + Vector3(x, -3, y);
}

function Update () {
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && Hit()) {
        var cube = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
        cube.transform.position = hit.transform.position + hit.normal;
    }
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1) && Hit())
        Destroy(hit.transform.gameObject);

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Keypad1)) {
        cube.renderer.material.color = Color.red;
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Keypad2)) {
        cube.renderer.material.color = Color.blue;
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Keypad3)) {
        cube.renderer.material.color = Color.yellow;
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Keypad4)) {
        cube.renderer.material.color = Color.green;
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Keypad5)) {
        cube.renderer.material.color = Color.magenta;
    }
}

function Hit() : boolean {
    return Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.forward, hit, range, 1);
}
```

Comment: How about using a field to store color value? And when you instantiate a cube, set the cube's color to the stored color.

Comment: @Verv - The problem with that is that I want the player to be able to switch colors on-the-fly, without opening a separate GUI, but if there is a way to set the field value from a command, and hide the field, I would be all for it.